# How can I easily connect and disconnect my bluetooth speakers in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth, speakers, connection

I have a bluetooth speaker system in my windows 8.Is there any other way of connecting and disconnecting without re-adding the device with its drivers/going out of range and turning off bluetooth in windows 8?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I just found the solution:

- Right-click on the sound icon on the task bar
- Select playback device
- Right-click on your Bluetooth device
- Select connect or disconnect

Comment: Good find! I wonder however why Microsoft hid it so deep. It's a real hassle if I wanna switch between Bluetooth audio transmission from PC and music streaming from smartphone via Spotify Connect to Wi-Fi speaker :(

Comment: hah jeez thanks! was driving me crazy that I had to "remove" the device every time I wanted to stop using it. this is gonna save me a lot of time.

Comment: does not persist settings, connects it regardless after restart of pc

Comment: How do I do to make this automatically connect whenever the PC and speakers are in range?
I know this should work since it did before I changed my WLAN adapter/module.

Comment: Unfortunatelly on my Windows 10 connect/disconnect actually does nothing, the 'set as default' option is grayed until i re-pair the device :S.

Comment: For your information on Windows 7 Lenovo computers they emulated a Windows looking dialog for toggling a bluetooth device on/off

An old Lenovo shortcut executes the following:

**"C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\BTWUIExt.exe"  /deviceAddr=f44efd008878**

So if you know the device address you can make a shortcut yourself or execute it from the start menu input field.

The address for the device can be found in the bluetooth tab when opening the bluetooth device properties. Just remove the : chars of identifier "f4:4e:fd:00:88:78"

Answer (score 2):

Initially:

- Right click on the sound icon on the task bar
- Select playback device
- Right click on your bluetooth device
- Select connect

Then:

- Go to Control -> Devices
- Right-click on bluetooth device
- Create shortcut on destop

When bluetooh is ON on both computer and device it automatically connects. It worked for me on BoatRockers wireless bluetooth earphone.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can unpair the device in PC Settings. First you'd have to search up "Bluetooth" in the charms bar search icon. Then click on Settings to get the results. Click on "Add Bluetooth Device". (Yes I know you don't want to add a bluetooth device but keep on reading) Right click on the device you want to remove and there you go device removed. But if you want to add it again then click on "Add a device".

Comment: This is exactly what the OP is trying to avoid. @Techbrunch's answer is the correct one.